# Rails Forms : change form fields from previously selected fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, simple-form, dynamicform

I have two **simple_form fields** like this:

```
<%= f.input :ration_card ,as: :radio_buttons,collection: ["Yes","No"], input_html: {id: "rationcard"} %>
<%= f.input :rationcardNum , label: "Ration Card No." ,input_html: {id: "rationcard_no"} %>
```

I want to **show the second field only if user selects "Yes" for the first field.** My Jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $("#rationcard").change(function(){
        if ($("#rationcard").val()=="Yes"){
            $("#rationcard_no").show();
        } else {
            $("#rationcard_no").hide();
        }
    })
})
```

I can see the js file being included at head of the page.

generated HTML:

```
<div class="control-group radio_buttons optional family_ration_card">
 <label class="radio_buttons optional control-label" for="rationcard">Ration card</label>
  <div class="controls">
   <label class="radio">
    <input id="rationcard" class="radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="Yes" name="family[ration_card]" checked="checked">
Yes
   </label>
  <label class="radio">
   <input id="rationcard" class="radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="No" name="family[ration_card]">
No
  </label>
 </div>
</div>  

<div class="control-group string optional family_rationcardNum">
 <label class="string optional control-label" for="rationcard_no">Ration Card No.</label>
  <div class="controls">
   <input id="rationcard_no" class="string optional" type="text" value="DGFR12" size="50" name="family[rationcardNum]">
  </div>
</div>
```

But the dynamic fields are not working. What is wrong here?

**Or suggest any better way to achieve this.**

Comment: Is form loaded using ajax ?

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors in the `js` file before the declaration of that jQuery function? I'd put an `alert` in there just to see if it pops up just to be sure it's executing. Also check the "view page source" to see if it looks correct.

Comment: Not putting this as an answer because I'm not completely sure, but if I recall correctly the "value" of the checkbox won't change as you click on it (try looking at it through a web debugger and see if it change as you click it). However if you do `$("#rationcard").prop("checked")` (returns a boolean) that will change each time (again, test in a web debugger).

Comment: @MrDanA yes the value of checkbox is not changing when I click on another option.

Comment: @TusharGupta No. form is not loaded using AJAX.

Comment: You need to use .live (in new versions of jquery, its on change events) method in jquery to update the change events on dynamically added dom elements.
for ex in latest versions of Jquery,
$(document).on('click', '#rationcard', function(e) {// code here});

Comment: **Added generated html** See question. @all

Comment: Good question. I'm was looking for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can't place id on inputs, because you will end up with two inputs with same and jQuery will only find the first one.
Secondly, you need to use $(this) inside your handler.

You need sth in line:

```
<%= f.input :ration_card ,as: :radio_buttons,collection: ["Yes","No"], wrapper_html: {id: "rationcard"} %>
<%= f.input :rationcardNum , label: "Ration Card No." ,wrapper_html: {id: "rationcard_no"} %>

$(function(){
    var toggle_rationcardNum = function(visible) {
        if (visible){
            $("#rationcard_no").show();
        } else {
            $("#rationcard_no").hide();
        }
    }

    $("#rationcard input").change(function(){
        toggle_rationcardNum($(this).val()=="Yes")
    })

    toggle_rationcardNum($("#rationcard input:checked").val()=="Yes")
})();
```

Comment: thant's working fine but it only hides the input filed of the second field and not the label. Added wrapper_html to botht the fields. Also I would like to know **what is this `wrapper_html`**?

Comment: input_html are all the html options which will be placed on inputs, wrapper_html are html option on wrapper - div in which those inputs are placed.

Comment: Well that doesn't work for checkboxes. :(  Also it doesn't automatically apply when the page loads. only works if clicked manually

Comment: Well, if you want this to work on load, you need to execute handler on load. I'll update answer. Could you explain what you mean by 'not working for checkboxes'?

Comment: It doesn't work If I have a checkbox field and another field which activates after the checkbox is "checked"

Comment: **Why doesn't `window.load` work on the jquery function?** I changed the function to `$(window).load(function() {});` But no use.

Comment: For checkboxes you need to modify handler a little, so conditions are met, however in this question you asked about radio buttons and I won't update answer to deal with this case as well. Please make a separate question for those. What did you expect to get by changing this to window.load?

Comment: that the javascript should be loaded when the window is loaded. I even tried `document.ready` for the same. Sorry but I'm new to JS.

Comment: @BroiSatse Well it doesn't work when you have iterative forms. (like nested forms for 2-3 persons which belong to a family). The above solution works for the first person only.

Comment: Again, that's because you cannot have two html elements with same id. If you want to work for multiple persons, you most likely want to wrap each user into some div and use classes instead of ids for inputs' wrappers. Then you need to rewrite the logic, so it shows the div with given_class within some parent div.