# Dynamically changing form fields from previously selected fields, iterative javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, simple-form

My question is almost similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18961515/1552570) one. Just a slight difference.

I have two models- **Family and Person** with `has_many` from family to person and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :persons` in family.rb

In my **FamiliesController** I have `edit` method for editing the records.There I'm using **nested forms** for a family and the corresponding persons. (So a single family can have many persons)

In my **edit.html.erb** I have form like:

```
<%= simple_form_for @family do |f| %>
  #family fields here
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :persons do |p| %>
   <%= p.input :gender,as: :radio_buttons,collection: ["Male","Female"],wrapper_html: {id: "gender"} %>
   <%= p.input :question,wrapper_html: {id: "question"} %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

**(Similar to the question as in the link)**

And I applied the same javascript as mentioned in the answer. ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18962516/1552570))

```
    $(function(){
    var toggle_gender = function(visible) {
        if (visible){
            $("#question").show();
        } else {
            $("#question").hide();
        }
    }

    $("#gender input").change(function(){
        toggle_gender($(this).val()=="Male")
    })

    toggle_gender($("#gender input:checked").val()=="Male")
})();
```

Generated HTML:

```
<div class="control-group radio_buttons required family_persons_gender gender">
 <label class="radio_buttons required control-label">
  <abbr title="required">*</abbr>
  Gender
 </label>
 <div class="controls">
  <label class="radio">
   <input id="family_persons_attributes_1_gender_male" class="radio_buttons required" type="radio" value="Male" name="family[persons_attributes][1][gender]" checked="checked">
Male
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
   <input id="family_persons_attributes_1_gender_female" class="radio_buttons required" type="radio" value="Female" name="family[persons_attributes][1][gender]">
Female
  </label>
 </div>
</div>  

<div class="control-group string required family_persons_mobnum mobnum">
 <label class="string required control-label" for="family_persons_attributes_1_mobnum">
  <abbr title="required">*</abbr>
  Mobile No.
 </label>
 <div class="controls">
  <input id="family_persons_attributes_1_mobnum" class="string required" type="text" value="9099067758" size="50" name="family[persons_attributes][1][mobnum]">
 </div>
</div>
```

But this **only works for the first person**. Meaning If I have 1 family and 3 persons the javascript only works for the first person. Why so?

Meaning **If there are 2 persons and I change the gender in 2nd person the javascript works on the first person and not on the 2nd person**

How do I fix this problem?

I read somewhere to use **iterative javascript (some even said underscore.js).**

**Or suggest any alternative way to do this**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your are using `id` to get the DOM elements. A page is supposed to have unique ids so jQuery matches the first element it finds with that id. You need to use `class`. Change the html and functions to sthing  like this (code not tested so beware):

```
<%= simple_form_for @family do |f| %>
  #family fields here
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :persons do |p| %>
   <%= p.input :gender,as: :radio_buttons,collection: ["Male","Female"],wrapper_html: {class: "gender"} %>
   <%= p.input :question,wrapper_html: {class: "question"} %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>


  $(function(){
    var toggle_gender = function(elem) {
       elem.closest(".gender").siblings('.question').toggle(elem.val() =="Male");

    }

    $(".gender input").change(function(){
       toggle_gender($(this))
    })

    $(".gender input:checked").each(function(){
       toggle_gender($(this))
    })

 })();
```

Comment: Will this work for all the the questions with the same class name?

Comment: when `gender input` changes it would search for the `question` for the same `person` and toggle its display. It should only toggle the one question related to the gender radio button and it should work for all 3.

Comment: **Updated question** Added the generated HTML. correspondingly changed the class in the js

Comment: is the question div in the html?

Comment: actually it is the `mobnum` div. I have also changed the js correspondingly. I had added `question` here just for the sake of asking on SO.

Comment: It is only working for particular cases. :( I tried it for the `gender` and `mobnum` But it doesn't work for rest of the form fields. What if the radio field question has 3 options?

Comment: it should be simple to fix the issue if the full html is known or you can try to change the script.

Comment: check it now...there was a small bug. Function name form ` toggle_gender` to  `toggle_computer` was not changed everywhere

Comment: It doesn't work for multiple fields.meaning if I write another `toggle` function for other two fields they don't work. check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jCHg/198/)

Comment: it was a js issue, only the first function was running but including both in one function works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2jCHg/202/)..if you need to have lots of such radio button then probably look for another approach as cant repeat the same function again and again

Comment: ya the number of options within quetion does not matter, as it toggles the whole div.